# append text to a textview

Tags: c#, macos, mono

i am creating a mac osx app using mono c#, im having some issues appending text to a text view which from xcode designer is NSTextView in an NSScrollView. I have tried

```
chat.InsertText(new NSString(str));
```

This does nothing though, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Borth NSString and NSAttributedString should work according to the doc but you could try to use  NSAttributedString just to see if you still have the same issue.